# Apache redirect query string

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm  new in building reverse proxy apache.

I've a query string like this:

- host.example.com/some/thing/?company=string with spaces l.t.d.

And i want it to be seen like:

- host.example.com/some/thing/string with spaces l.t.d.

I've written this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING]} ^company=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/some/thing$ /some/thing/%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

But  both the RewriteCond and RewriteRule don't work.

Any help it's really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Did you activate the rewrite log? It shows what/why things happen

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not matching against the %{QUERY_STRING} variable, remove the **]**  from the variable .

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^company=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?some/thing$ /some/thing/%1? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, I've writteng it wrong :(

I did exactly what you suggest, but it doesn't work